# mysql selection preference

Tags: mysql

I'm wanting to display random adverts on my front end that are selected from a table. Each advert has a score between 1 and 5. The higher the advert score, the more frequently it should be selected

Is there any way I could achieve this in a query? So maybe something like

```
SELECT * FROM advert ORDER BY RAND(), (SOME MAGICAL PREFERENCE ORDERING) LIMIT 3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT * FROM advert ORDER BY RAND() * (SOME MAGICAL PREFERENCE ORDERING) DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'm not understanding your answer though.

Comment: @agh: what actually you don't get? The query is trivial

Comment: I've never seen order by rand() * ? before. So you're saying my query should be something like SELECT * FROM advert ORDER BY RAND() * score DESC LIMIT 3 ?

Comment: @agh: `RAND()` is a function that returns random number in `0..1` and `*` is a **multiplication** sign. So random number multiplied to the score comes to `weight`. The bigger weight the row has - the more chances for it to be shown